# Hidden Markov model library

Tags: hidden-markov-model, software, c++

I am looking for a free hidden markov model libraries in C/C++. I can google and get a list, but a it is impossible to tell which free ones are industry standard and well established. Can anyone provide guidance on this.

Maybe the right way to put it would be, what hidden markov model library would you use on the speech recognition system you used to lock your house with a passphrase (ya, I expect anyone on this forum knows not to do that) -- assume that you are impatient and don't like waiting around for your house to decide it is you, i.e. performance counts for a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This seems very good one:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvhmm/

Some times ago I developed a HMM libs, but it is only with discrete states so no speech recognition. You can find it [here](https://github.com/nkint/ofxSequence). Adding the missing part should not be too hard, also because I used the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) linear algebra lib for translating from some Matlab code that can handle any kind of data.

I studied a little bit the theory and the code from this C# super good library:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541428/Sequence-Classifiers-in-Csharp-Part-I-Hidden-Marko

Hope it helps!